# criterios como títulos y subcriterios como contenido MySQL PHP Smarty

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, smarty

Tengo tres tablas relacionadas, Estado, Ciudades, Escuelas. Mi objetivo es tener **Estado** como título, **Ciudad** como subtítulo y una lista de las escuelas de la ciudad.

- Estado1

  - Ciudad1

    - Escuela1
    - Escuela2
    - Escuela3
  - Ciudad2

    - Escuela4
    - Escuela5
    - Escuela6
    - Escuela7
- Estado2

  - Ciudad3

    - Escuela8
    - Escuela9
  - Ciudad4

    - Escuela10
    - Escuela11
    - Escuela12
    - Escuela13

Llamo datos de la base de datos:

```
// consulto la base de datos
  $res = $db->prepare("SELECT estados.estado, ciudades.ciudad, escuelas.escuela 
  FROM estados
  LEFT JOIN ciudades
  ON estados.id=ciudades.idEstado
  LEFT JOIN escuelas
  ON ciudades.id=escuelas.idCiudad");
   $res->execute(); 
   $res->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_LAZY); 
 //mando a smarty 
  $smarty->assign('res',$res);
```

Luego en el archivo.tpl

```
     <ul>
        {foreach $res as $r}
           <li>{$r.estado}
                <ul>
                    {foreach $r.ciudad as $c}
                    <li>{$c}
                        <ul>
                           {foreach $r.escuela as $e}
                           <li>{$e}</li>
                           {/foreach}
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    {/foreach}
                </ul>
           </il>
         {/foreach}
        </ul>
```

Y obtengo lo siguiente:

- Estado1

  - Ciudad 1

    - Escuela 1
- Estado1

  - Ciudad 1

    - Escuela 2
- Estado1

  - Ciudad 1

    - Escuela 3
- Estado1

  - Ciudad 2

    - Escuela 4
- Estado1

  - Ciudad 2

    - Escuela 5
- Estado1

  - Ciudad 2

    - Escuela 6
- Estado1

  - Ciudad 3

    - Escuela 7
- Estado1

  - Ciudad 3

    - Escuela 8

Comment: te falta lógica dentro del bucle y te sobran bucles. Solo debes pintas el primero y comprobar(almacenando en una variable) si el Estado/Ciudad que tienes que pintar es nueva o no, aun así, primero haría un `var_dump($res);` para ver que la consulta es correcta, si no lo entiendes pongo un ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

No se de php smarty, pero hasta donde logro entender esto se podría solucionar haciendo primero la consulta de los estados y mientras se esté obtenido cada dato hacer dentro de este ciclo la consulta a las ciudades y, al igual que los estados, hacer dentro de este la consulta a las escuelas.

Sería algo así en php normal

```
Echo "<ul>";
$e = mysqli_query ($conexion, consulta a los estados);
While ($estado = mysqli_fetch_object($e)) {
Echo "<li>".$estado->nombre."</li>";
$c = mysqli_query ($conexion, consulta a las ciudades);
While ($ciudad = mysqli_fetch_object($c)) {
Echo "<li>".$ciudad->nombre."</li>";
$es = mysqli_query ($conexion, consulta a las escuelas);
While ($escuela = mysqli_fetch_object($es)) {
Echo "<li>".$escuela->nombre."</li>";
}

}

}
Echo "</ul>";
```

Esto es para que tengas una idea.

Comment: Gracias Edwin, voy a probar tu sugerencia.

Comment: Yo no lo haría... Ademas de que no ha solventado el problema de las variables/consultas que se le pasan ( ya que irán cambiando por cada Estado/Ciudad) la idea de hacer consultas a una base de datos dentro de un bucle no es muy aconsejable...Cuanto menos uno dentro de otro

Comment: No comprendo tu argumento.

Answer (score 0):

Hacer `var_dump()` me ayudó, gracias por sugerirlo Carlos Gª-muñoz. Así resolví la consulta a la base de datos y quedó así:

```
$res = $db->prepare("SELECT estados.estado, ciudades.ciudad, escuelas.escuela 
  FROM estados
  LEFT JOIN ciudades
  ON estados.id=ciudades.idEstado
  LEFT JOIN escuelas
  ON ciudades.id=escuelas.idCiudad");
   $res->execute(); 
   $res->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
   $array_deseado = array();
   foreach($res as $r){
        $array_deseado[$r['estado']][$r['ciudad']][]=$r['escuela'];
   } 
 //mando a smarty 
  $smarty->assign('escuela',$array_deseado);
```

Lugo en el archivo .tpl, usando Smarty 3.1.3, resolví así:

```
    <ul>
    {foreach $escuela as $est}
       <li>{$est@key}
           <ul>
           {foreach $est["ciudad"] as $ciu}
              <li>{$ciu@key}
                  <ul>
                  {foreach $ciu as $esc}
                      <li>{$esc}</li>
                  {/foreach}
                  </ul>
              </li>
           {/foreach}
           </ul>
       </il>
     {/foreach}
    </ul>
```